# How to group by 3 columns -and- get a count in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create some SQL that groups by three columns and then gets the `COUNT` of those rows that form that grouped result.

Also, ordered by the highest count, first.

[I've created a SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/41c33/3) to help me.

Table schema (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo]
(
    [FooId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Company] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ProductFirstname] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ProductLastname] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
)
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('2001-10-01T07:07:07', 'Red', 'Yummy', 'GummyBear');
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('2002-10-01T07:07:07', 'Red', 'Yummy', 'GummyBear');
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('2003-10-01T07:07:07', 'Red', 'Bannana', 'Cake');
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('2003-11-11T07:07:07', 'Red', 'Green', 'Apples');
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('2004-10-01T07:07:07', 'Red', 'Yummy', 'GummyBear');
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('2005-10-01T07:07:07', 'Blue', 'Yummy', 'GummyBear');
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('2006-10-01T07:07:07', 'Blue', 'Yummy', 'GummyBear');
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('2007-10-01T07:07:07', 'Blue', 'Yummy', 'GummyBear');
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('2008-10-01T07:07:07', 'Red', 'Yummy', 'GummyBear');
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('2009-10-01T07:07:07', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Apples');
```

Expected result:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Company | Name            | Count |
+-----------------------------------+
|    Red   | Yummy GummyBear | 4    |
|   Blue   | Yummy GummyBear | 3    |
|    Red   | Bannana Cake    | 1    |
|    Red   | Green Apples    | 1    |
|   Blue   | Green Apples    | 1    |
+-----------------------------------+
```

So with this data, `CreatedOn` is basically ignored. It's some meta data for another use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    Company
    , ISNULL(ProductFirstname, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(ProductLastName, '') NAME
    , COUNT(*) Count
FROM foo
GROUP BY Company
    ,ISNULL(ProductFirstname, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(ProductLastName, '')
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Here is a working [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/583ed/6)

Comment: Whoa - what is `ORDER BY 3 DESC` ?

Comment: @Pure.Krome It orders the result on the 3rd column, descending. I've done that in order to get the list ordered as it is in your example. I could have also used `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`. You can specify the column "number" only. Obviously if you change the order of the columns it will still order the result based on the 3rd column, so sometimes you might want to **explicitly** say on which column you want ordering (in this scenario by using `COUNT(*) DESC` instead of `3 DESC`, but I have used it for simplicity). Is it clear now?

Comment: If you replace `3` with `COUNT(*) DESC` .. will that make the compiler do a 2nd `COUNT(*)` or just use the results from the `SELECT` ? ie. is it faster/cheaper to use `3` or it makes no diff (besides visual).

Comment: @Pure.Krome I honestly haven't tested to see which is more performant, but I have used both and it did not make any difference in my cases, hence I did not need to search for which is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
Select company, name, count(*) as count from
(
select
  company,
  (ProductFirstname + ProductLastName) as name,
from foo
)T 
group by company, name
Order by 3 desc
```